# Rails3/Mongoid - Basic db:seed with embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using MongoID with rails 3.1. and I would like to seed my database (both in dev and production). I have a Pages model with Feeds embedded. What's the best way for me to seed the embedded feeds for each page? I can easily seed all of the page data just not the embedded feeds. Please note that I'm looking to actual have real unique data for these pages/feeds not just arbitrary test data. thanks!

page.rb (model)

```
...
embeds_many :feeds
```

feed.rb (model)

```
class Feed
include Mongoid::Document
field :source, :type => String
field :user, :type => String
```

embedded_in :page, :inverse_of => :feeds
end

db/seeds.rb

```
Page.create(title: "Page 1", userID: "EMAIL@gmail.com", presentation: 'cards', customURL: 'testing1')
Page.create(title: "Page 2", userID: "EMAIL@gmail.com", presentation: 'cards', customURL: 'testing2')
Page.create(title: "Page 3", userID: "EMAIL@gmail.com", presentation: 'cards', customURL: 'testing3')
Page.create(title: "Page 4", userID: "EMAIL@gmail.com", presentation: 'cards', customURL: 'testing4')
Page.create(title: "Page 5", userID: "EMAIL@gmail.com", presentation: 'cards', customURL: 'testing5')
```

How best can I embed some feed data in each page? Thanks much.

Comment: You can also write your seeds file using `.find_or_create_by, .first_or_create! (etc)`, so if you update your application and your `seeds` file, your can rerun `rake db:seed` without wiping your database or risk duplicating data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Page.create(title: "blah", feeds: [
  Feed.new(source: "blahblah", user: "me!"),
  Feed.new(....),
  Feed.new(.....),
])
```

Is how I do it in my `db:seed`, I even have a few that are multiple documents deep.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  page = Page.create(title: "Page #{i}", userID: "EMAIL@gmail.com", presentation: 'cards', customURL: "testing#{i}")

  3.times { Feed.create(page: page) }
end
```

Comment: cool, yeah what I'd like to do is actual seed the database with real pages and feeds tho. So unlike my example it won't so much be page 1, page 2, page 3, it will be like 10 real unique pages. I just need to know how to spell that out. Thanks.